# How can you stop the Playbook from only displaying a square instead of an image?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-playbook, zepto

I'm currently having a of problem with my Phonegap application on Playbook. It consists of a button and a circle that moves across the screen. The circle is re with a black border, but the playbook renders it as just a red square. Does anyone know of how to fix this? I've tried changing the image type and adding in a background color tag, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple div with css 3 properties to create a simple circle without images.

```
background: red;
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
-moz-border-radius: 5em;
-webkit-border-radius: 5em;
border: solid 1px #000;
border-radius: 5em;
```